# Answer your own question FAQ - links broken

Tags: bug, broken-link, blog

Our FAQ (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) links to blog posts that got broken today.

Is this temporary, and will the links work again, or should we update the FAQ?

Comment: Looks like it is temporarily broken; I'll ping the blog devs.

Comment: And this happened before; apparently the static blog builder can fail half-way through and then those older posts are not included and the links 404 instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters static blog builder?? And here I am, thinking it's all sitting safely in database. Oh well... :)